# Getting TypeError trying to open() a file in write mode with Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, file, typeerror

I have a Python script that in my mind should:

1. Open a file
2. Save its content in a variable
3. For each line in the variable:

   1. Edit it with a regular expression
   2. Append it to another variable
4. Write the second variable to the original file

Here is a MWE version of the script:

```
# [omitting some setup]

with open(setFile, 'r') as setFile:
    olddata = setFile.readlines()

newdata = ''

for line in olddata:
    newdata += re.sub(regex, newset, line)

with open(setFile, 'w') as setFile:
    setFile.write(newdata)
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File C:\myFolder\myScript.py, line 11, in <module>
        with open(setFile, 'w') as setFile:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

As far as I can understand, Python is complaining about receiving the `setFile` variable as an argument of `open()` because it isn't of the expected type, but then why did it accept it before (when I only read the file)?

I suppose that my mistake is quite evident but, as I am a neophyte in Python, I can't find out where  it is. Could anyone give me a help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just curious why you are using the same variable name for your file and then as your filehandler and then again in your next with function.

_io.TextIOWrapper is the object from your previous open, which has been asssigned to the setFile variable.
try:

```
with open(setFile, 'r') as readFile:
    olddata = readFile.readlines()
newdata = ''
for line in olddata:
    newdata += re.sub(regex, newset, line)
with open(setFile, 'w') as writeFile:
    writeFile.write(newdata)
```

Comment: Well, to be honest it's only laziness. So, as I supposed, my mistake was something incredibly stupid. Thank you very much!

Comment: laziness is the source of most of my programming